# exim refusing to handle virtual domains after upgrade to debian stretch

Tags: exim, debian-stretch

I have a machine that handles multiple virtual domains. Some of these include aliases defined for those specific domains (domain names will be changed from real names).

I have, for example:

```
$ cat /etc/exim4/virtual/alias.domain.com
hibak: "|/usr/local/bin/mail2redmine.sh blah"
```

And, of course `alias.domain.com` is included in `dc_other_hostnames` in `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf`.

It worked fine on debian jessie, but after upgrading to stretch, the virtual hostnames ceased to work. Getting a letter for them created such an entry in the rejectlog:

```
2018-02-19 17:03:21 H=from.host [REDACTED] F=<REDACTED> rejected RCPT <hibak@alias.domain.com>: Unrouteable address
```

`exim -bt hibak@alias.domain.com` returns

```
R: system_aliases for hibak@alias.domain.com
hibak@alias.domain.com is undeliverable: Unrouteable address
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the wonderful debug mode for exim (`exim -d -bt foo@bar`), thus being able to compare what goes on in a debian jessie and debian stretch system with virtual domains.

The main difference seems to be that the `vdom_aliases` router is missing from `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template`, which got updated without prompting during upgrade as I did not modify it at all before. I copied the section for the `vdom_aliases` router from `exim4.conf.template.dpkg-old`, and it started working.